# How do I formally test outliers from a linear regression?

Tags: regression, hypothesis-testing, repeated-measures, outliers

I have a set of data that looks at the area of remaining retina against age. I have three points of data per patient. We know that over time, the area of remaining retina decreases exponentially. I have done a linear regression to model loss of area over time (see graph). X axis = age, Y axis = retinal area (log scale).

In this data there are some patients that are outliers because of their genetic mutation. I am interested in doing a formal test to see whether because of this mutation, they have a significantly larger area of retina remaining for their age, compared to the rest of the cohort. I have read about various tests (Grubbs, Dixon etc) but they don't seem to apply here for bivariate data. I am aware that I can identify outliers by visualising them, but I want a formal test with a p value if possible to satisfy reviewers who have requested it.

Please see the attached graph to demonstrate what the data looks like. The red and green dots are the patients I am interested in testing. Any suggestions on how to analyse this would be most appreciated. I am using Prism 7 for analysis. I can't seem to find an answer for this question on stack anywhere. As you can probably tell, my stats experience is fairly limited. Thanks for your help.

[image: Age vs Area of retina (mm2)]

Comment: Welcome to our site.  Could you please explain what is shown on the two axes of your plot?  And what do those two to three points per patient actually mean?  They represent an important complication that renders standard outlier tests invalid, so it's of interest to understand them better.

Comment: Thanks for your response, and apologies if that wasn't clear. This is tracking rate of degeneration of the retina (in the eye) against age. So the y axis is retinal area (mm2, log scale) and x axis is age. Each set of three points are one patient, with a measurement annually for three years (to track a rate of progression). Each of the patients in grey have a particular type of genetic mutation, while the coloured dots have another type. I am looking to explain why there are different degeneration rates between these patients.